# Dimension too large on a PNG figure under xelatex and beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, xetex, errors, jpeg

I have PNG image I want to introduce into my presentation. The figure is black and white and the edges are small. When I compile the file in `pdflatex` everything is fine but when I Compile it with `xelatex` I get `!dimension too large` error:

```
[1] <use  "./figs/surface.png" > [2]
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.31 \end{frame}
```

The line I use:

```
  \includegraphics<2> [width=0.8\textwidth]{./figs/surface.png}\par
```

And the file:[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Coarse-Grained (CG) simulation of a membrane}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics<2> [width=0.8\textwidth]{./figs/surface.png}\par
      \includegraphics<3> [width=1.0\textwidth]{./figs/a_lipid_CG.jpg}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item bla
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Here are links to the used files:
http://www.4shared.com/photo/EK4CPOF2/a_lipid_CG.html  http://www.4shared.com/photo/un7JtzXa/surface.html

Comment: Make a complete example that demonstrates your error (I have a lot doubts that really the graphics itself is the problem)

Comment: Using your image in both places I don't get any error.

Comment: A *complete* example should start with `\documentclass`. And make sure that you make the real graphic available.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The file I have uploaded (surface.png) is the one that I use. Do you think it is the other file (a_lipid_CG.jpg) that cause the error?

Comment: @egreg: What do you mean ''both places''?

Comment: I mean "for both `\includegraphics`"

Comment: @egreg: did you try with the ``bigger`` option?

Comment: Yes, I did; it doesn't seem to change much.

Comment: @Yotam: Upload scripts can change a picture, e.g. resize it. So better but both pictures in a zip-file somewhere for download.

Comment: @Yotam The error message makes it clear that the image `./figs/surface.png` has been successively included and even shipped out (on page `[2]`). So the error must come later.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Thanks. I understand what you mean. Still, the pasted code produce an error (running xelatex) which I don't know how to solve.

Comment: The `a_lipid_CG.jpg` seems to cause the issue. I get the same error with `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics{a_lipid_CG.jpg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`. Note that the `[1] <use  "./figs/surface.png" > [2]` is not part of the error message, but only a info message printed before it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243753/is-it-imagemagicks-fault-or-pdflatexs-that-some-jpegs-arent-working which has the technical details in the answers: The image file is missing a JFIF header with `ResolutionUnit`, `XResolution` and `YResolution`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `a_lipid_CG.jpg` seems to cause the issue. As explained below this specific JPG seems to be incompatible with XeTeX.

I get the same error with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics{a_lipid_CG.jpg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}.
```

Note that the `[1] <use  "./figs/surface.png" > [2]` is not part of the error message, but only a info message printed before it.

After running the JPG image through the conversion tool of Image Magick `convert`, i.e. `convert a_lipid_CG.jpg a_lipid_CG2.jpg` and testing the document with this new JPG file, the error disappears. This leads me to the conclusion that your particular JPG file is not fully compatible with XeTeX. Apparently XeTeX has issues reading the size from the meta-data from the JPG, which somehow leads to the "too-large" error.

To fix this please open the JPG file in an image manipulation program and save it again.

Comment: As an aside, I know that `pdftex` has issues with some JFIF headers, resulting in wrong resolution info and thus wrong image dimensions. For instance, it may be that the image has 300dpi, but `pdftex` doesn't get this info and assumes 72dpi, resulting in scaling the image too large. AFAIK, the source of the error lies in the `xpdf` library used by `pdftex` for image inclusion. There could also be issues with included thumbnails, i.e. the dimensions of the thumbnail are reported, but the whole image is output. Correct me if I'm wrong, this isn't really my area of expertise.

Comment: I had to convert mine to a png to solve the problem. Very weird bug.

Comment: Saving as PNG works for me too, using GIMP.

Answer (score 14):

Similarly to what @Martin-Scharrer said, `convert`/`mogrify` worked for me too, but only by explicitly adding a resolution, which seemed to have been missing.  So the following fixed the problem (the files had been produced with matplotlib, btw):

```
mogrify -density 90 myfile.png
```

Comment: Thank you, this did for me too. Without specifying a resolution, it wouldn't go.

Comment: Worked for me without resolution, although I was resizing which I wanted to do for other reasons: `convert picture.jpg -resize 50% picture.png`. I hoped that converting back to JPG using ImageMagic `convert` will give me a valid JPG, but it did not. However, JPG in general works for me with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I just had a similar issue, and your mogrify trick worked for me on an image not generated by matplotlib, thanks a lot!