# Why can't XeTeX handle this dank meme?

Tags: graphics, xetex, jpeg

#### MWE

Please use the image linked to below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{dank}
\end{document}
```

Oddly enough, only *this* picture fails and *only* when compiling with XeTeX (as opposed to pdfTeX or LuaTeX):

```
ERROR: Dimension too large.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.5 \includegraphics{dank}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

[The dank meme itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFXEF.jpg) is a bit of an eyesore, so I'm not displaying it inline.  Please check the shasum to make sure it's still the same file when you download it.

```
$ shasum dank.jpg
b889bc28b2ccd079073267159db0562f45b58e4d  dank.jpg
```

What's special about this image?  Why does it fail?  Its natural setting (as seen with LuaTeX or pdfTeX) is well under 19 feet.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51164/24974

Comment: Can I ask what context prompted dank memes in LaTeX? This question's title took me completely by surprise.

Comment: @ArunDebray I'm helping someone clean up and improve a LaTeX guide and, alas, it had this dank meme.

Comment: @SeanAllred Ah, thanks! Well, if erik's suggestion doesn't work for you, you have a wonderful excuse to substitute a different picture...

Comment: @ArunDebray I know that changing/re-saving/etc. the picture will allow me to continue – I'm more interested in what's stumped XeTeX in the first place ;)

Comment: A combination of no preferred width in the `\includegraphics` command and an image with a wildly off-base DPI setting, maybe even as low as 1 DPI?

Comment: @MikeRenfro You can set any width you'd like (e.g. `[width=1cm]`) – no change. How are you getting the DPI information?

Comment: Beside it is too wide at `scale=1`, there are something wrong in the JPG format, that for some reason only is a problem for xetex. If you edit this file with The Gimp an then save it **without changes** with  quality 100%,  the problem disappear.

Comment: I didn't get any dpi information myself. Just made a guess. Should be able to get it from any decent image viewer (IrfanView: Image / Info; Preview: Command-I, etc.). Are you saying the dpi info was something sensible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason is that dank.jpg does not have JFIF, or Exif header.
So jpeg driver of XeTeX cannot read density and assumes
that it is 1DPI. Thus it becomes very large.
The jpeg driver of pdftex also cannot read the density,
so assumes it is 72DPI.
Solution: Use convert in ImageMagick to add JFIF header.

```
convert -density 72x72 dank.jpg dank1.jpg
```

Then converted dank1.jpg will be OK for XeTeX.

---

To determine if this is the problem with a given image, use (copied from @egreg's comment): `identify -verbose dank.jpg | grep Resolution`.

Comment: How did you determine that it didn't have the appropriate headers, though?

Comment: @SeanAllred With `identify -verbose dank.jpg|grep Resolution` you get no information, but you get `Resolution: 72x72` for `dank1.jpg`