# PDF image not rendering

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf

A co-worker and I both use Latex. If I create a pdf image to use, it does not show up. However, my co-worker can save an image as a pdf and it renders just fine. Is there documentation about how to save an image to pdf? I'm using Photoshop to save as Photoshop pdf with XeLaTeX as my typesetting engine. If my co-worker sends me images he's made, then it renders just fine so it has to be settings in the saved pdf. Anyone know what they are?

Comment: Can you give us the actual pdf picture that causes the problem and the code you use?

Comment: I seem to rrecall having a problem long ago with Xelatex not being able to successfully `\includegraphics`, but I can't recall what the resolution to the problem was.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- could this be relevant? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273265/55879

Comment: @ArunDebray Thanks.  That may have been the problem... that it was peculiar to a particular set of images.

Answer (score 4):

xdvipdfmx in the TeX Live 2015 rejects by default to include
PDF images of version newer than 1.5. The next version of
xdvipdfmx does not reject such kind of images.
As a workaround until you obtain the next xdvipdfmx, use an option

```
--output-driver="xdvipdfmx -q -E -V 7"
```

For example,

```
xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -q -E -V 7" filename.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the comments and suggestions. Here's what I found that worked. With any image in Photoshop CC 2015, select Save As. Choose Photoshop PDF. I also tick the Save As a Copy box so it doesn't save over the original. When I click Save, I get a dialog box that states the settings you choose n the Save Adobe PDF dialog can override your current settings in the Save As dialog box. Click Ok and the Save Adobe PDF box opens.

Compatibility must be Acrobat 6 (PDF 1.5). Anything higher & the pdf image won't render in Latex. On the Output tab, the Profile Inclusion Policy defaults to "Include Destination Profile". You must change this to "Don't Include Profile". Those are all the settings.

In other programs when exporting as PDF, I check the options and have discovered the checkbox labeled "Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded" must be unchecked so that fonts can be embedded.