# Why is this PNG image (with transparency) going crazy when I include it?

Tags: graphics, png

Nothing's wrong with the PNG as far as I'm aware, but I'm getting some wacky behavior from it (MWE below).  The problem goes away when I remove `-transparent white` from the ImageMagick options.

#### MWE

```
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
\begin{filecontents*}{heart.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(26.37104, 0, 0, 24.680786, 232.422821, 233.229111)" style="fill: rgb(223, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1;">
    <path style="fill:#df0000;fill-opacity:1" d="M 3.676,-9 C 0.433,-9 0,-5.523 0,-5.523 0,-5.523 -0.433,-9 -3.676,-9 -5.946,-9 -8,-7.441 -8,-4.5 -8,-0.614 -1.4208493,3.2938141 0,9 1.35201,3.2985969 8,-0.614 8,-4.5 8,-7.441 5.946,-9 3.676,-9 z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents*}
\immediate\write18{convert -units PixelsPerInch -size 2000x2000 heart.svg -density 600 -trim -transparent white heart.png}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\CHeart[1][]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,#1]{heart.png}}

\begin{document}
\CHeart
\end{document}
```

Output: (blank pdf sometimes, other times…)

[image: output]

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.6-7 Q16 x86_64 2016-12-07 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png rsvg tiff xml zlib
```

---

Using `-background none` before the SVG (instead of `-transparent white` before the PNG) gets me this lovely 'modern art':

[image: output]

Comment: Some checks: `heart.svg` has the same contents as in the TeX source. `heart.png` is correctly converted, checked by file date and image viewer. The correct `heart.png` is found and included by LaTeX, checked by inspecting the `.log` file.

Comment: I wonder: could this be similar to [Why can't XeTeX handle this dank meme?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273265/17423)?

Comment: I doubt it, neither you have reported an error message nor it is a JPEG file. Also, XeTeX is not able to invent a second heart. I expect the error at an earlier stage, see my previous comment.

Comment: [I'm starting to think something is just wacko on my machine…](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwLut.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a bug with OS X's Preview application – it works fine when I use Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

I do get the expected normal heart with transparent background with option `-transparent white` or a white background with `-background none`. Compiler: `pdflatex -shell-escape` and `xelatex -shell-escape`

Version of ImageMagick: 6.9.5-7 Q16 x86_64 2016-08-27

Version of XeTeX: 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)

### Transparent background

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}% overwriting environment "filecontents"
\begin{filecontents*}{heart.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(26.37104, 0, 0, 24.680786, 232.422821, 233.229111)" style
    <path style="fill:#df0000;fill-opacity:1" d="M 3.676,-9 C 0.433,-9 0,-5.523
  </g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents*}
\immediate\write18{convert -units PixelsPerInch -size 2000x2000 heart.svg -densi
%\immediate\write18{convert -units PixelsPerInch -size 2000x2000 heart.svg -dens
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\CHeart[1][]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,#1]{heart.png}}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\noindent
\CHeart
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with transparent background]

### White background

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}% overwriting environment "filecontents"
\begin{filecontents*}{heart.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(26.37104, 0, 0, 24.680786, 232.422821, 233.229111)" style
    <path style="fill:#df0000;fill-opacity:1" d="M 3.676,-9 C 0.433,-9 0,-5.523
  </g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents*}
%\immediate\write18{convert -units PixelsPerInch -size 2000x2000 heart.svg -dens
\immediate\write18{convert -units PixelsPerInch -size 2000x2000 heart.svg -densi
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\CHeart[2][]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,#1]{heart.png}}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\noindent
\CHeart
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with white background]

The standard environment `filecontents` does not overwrite the file. If the contents of `heart.svg` changes, the file must be deleted first to get the new version on the next compile run.

The example uses package `filecontents` which always overwrites the files.

`\pagecolor{yellow}` is used to show the different background types.

## TikZ version

The path description of the SVG file can directly be used in TikZ to get a vector graphics without external image file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{heartred}{RGB}{223, 0, 0}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \tikz\fill[heartred, yscale=-1] svg {
    M 3.676,-9 C 0.433,-9 0,-5.523 0,-5.523 0,-5.523 -0.433,-9 -3.676,
    -9 -5.946,-9 -8,-7.441 -8,-4.5 -8,-0.614 -1.4208493,3.2938141 0,
    9 1.35201,3.2985969 8,-0.614 8,-4.5 8,-7.441 5.946,-9 3.676,-9 z
  };%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you get different behavior with xelatex, perhaps?

Comment: @SeanAllred I get the same behavior with `xelatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)`?

Comment: @SeanAllred The version of XeTeX is the same.